# Why is HideRowLabels() method missing in wxpython grid class?

Tags: python, methods, wxpython

In http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/grid.Grid.html?highlight=hiderowlabels reference page, I see that HideRowLabels() method of wx.grid class listed. But when I use it in my application, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Grid' object has no attribute 'HideRowLabels'
```

the same goes with `DisableRowResize()` method.

I use  wx `'2.8.12.1'` version at Windows 7.

Please explain,
best regards

Comment: Have you tried `SetRowLabelSize(0)`?

Comment: No. Why are those methods missing? I need `DisableRowResize()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have documentation for the next iteration of `wxPython` called [**Phoenix**](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix) which identifies itself as version `3.0.0.0`. It is currently in development.

The documentation for your wxPython version is located at either:

- **http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.Grid-class.html**
- **http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/grid/wx.grid.Grid.html**

Comment: Thanks, why isnt it mentioned that HideRowLabels() is a new method coming with wxpython 2.9?

Comment: Where would you expect to see it mentioned? In Phoenix documentation? I do not know, I always considered wxPython docs a bit shortcoming. Some effort is needed to understand what is stored where and what is contained there. Not very user friendly.